# Oracle generated column aliases different on two DB's

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a legacy application we cannot modify that connects to Oracle 11g and at some point runs a query and returns a result. The application however is using the "generated" column name from Oracle to read the result.

Consider the following query:

```
select nvl(1,0.0) from DUAL;
```

As this query does not specify an alias, the generated column name would be "nvl(1,0.0)"

However on another server the generated column name is "nvl(1,0)"  (notice 0 and not 0.0) and the application fails.

Is there a configuration that can be changed for Oracle? I've searched for formatting and locale configurations and they are equal on both servers.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there's a parameter called cursor_sharing that was set to FORCE instead of EXACT

```
select nvl(1,0.0) from DUAL;
```

The query above returns the following depending on the value of the parameter:

```
FORCE=NVL(1,0)
EXACT=NVL(1,0.0)
```